# Handling when user enters a very large number

Tags: c, integer

I am a bit stuck

How do I handle,(in this case exit my program) when the user types in a very very large (greater than the amount that an integer can hold) OR when the user types in a amount that is very very small (less than an amount that C can hold)

```
    int read_integer(){
    int value;
    scanf("%d",&value);
    if(value > INT_MAX){
        printf("Error: Value is too large");
        exit(1);
    }

    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `scanf()` function cannot detect out of range inputs, but you can use `strtol()`.

If the input is out of range, it returns the minimum or maximum value of the range (so it cannot be used to input those two values). The code also checks that the next character was the string terminator, or a newline (you might use `fgets()` for the input).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[100];
    char *eptr;
    scanf("%99s", str);
    long val = strtol(str, &eptr, 10);
    if(*eptr != '\0' && *eptr != '\n')
        printf("Not a number\n");
    else if(val == LONG_MIN || val == LONG_MAX)
        printf("Out of range\n");
    else
        printf("Input %ld\n", val);
    
    return 0;
}
```