# Is C scanf() prohibited from checking that integers are in range?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, scanf, integer-overflow

[I learned today](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75910950/4323) that `scanf()` in C does not check if integers are representable in the specified type.  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    short num;
    int ret = scanf("%hd", &num);
    printf("read %d, returned %d\n", num, ret);
    return 0;
}
```

On my system (Clang/MacOS), the above program will say "returned 1" meaning `scanf()` read the specified token even if the input is not representable, such as `4223215425243525443245234453`.  `man scanf` says:

> Scanning stops when an input character does not match such a format character.  Scanning also stops when an input conversion cannot be made.

**Does the C standard *require* this behavior**, or would it also be permissible for an implementor of `scanf()` to consider out-of-range numeric inputs invalid (and so return 0 in cases like the above)?  If this behavior is required, I'd appreciate a quote from the standard saying so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> If this object does not have an appropriate type, or if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the object, the behavior is [undefined](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p10).

So absolutely anything is permissible.

Comment: Thanks.  I wonder why there's no mention of this UB in e.g.  https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf or https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

Comment: @JohnZwinck, the manual page at linux.die.net documents Glibc's version of the `scanf`-family functions.  Also, it was probably written by a developer, not a language lawyer.  The cppreference page was probably produced by a technical writer, but again, not necessarily a language lawyer.  The bottom line is that neither of these is authoritative for what the language specification says (or does not say).

Comment: @JohnBollinger Re: "(or does not say)". Consider library functions. The C standard (all revisions) does not require from library functions _not_ to do anything outside of their descriptions. (I keep wondering why.) This implies that `strcmp` (for example) is permitted to check an email (for example) on top of string comparison. Any thoughts 
/ comments?

Comment: @pmor as long as the effects are not visible from within the program, it can do whatever.

Comment: @pmor, specifically, every version of the standard to date has a version of C17's paragraph 5.1.2.3/6, which defines the "observable behavior" of a program, and specifies that conforming implementations will not produce more (or less or different) observable behavior than the language specifies.  The spec is intentionally silent on what other, non-observable behaviors a program may exhibit.  You might debate whether the standard's definition of "observable behavior" hits for what we expect based on its name, but I think it's pretty good.

Answer (score 8):

C11 7.21.6.2 The fscanf function /10, we see:

> If this object does not have an appropriate type, or if the result of
> the conversion cannot be represented in the object, the behavior is
> undefined.

Comment: Same for C18 I was about to post.

Answer (score 0):

"Is C scanf() **prohibited** from checking that integers are in range?"

According to linux scanf man-page @ https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf , there is no Prohibition :

```
Return Value

These functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the event of an early matching failure.  
[...] and errno is set indicate the error. 

[...]  

ERANGE

The result of an integer conversion would exceed the size that can be stored in the corresponding integer type. 

Conforming To

The functions fscanf(), scanf(), and sscanf() conform to C89 and C99 and POSIX.1-2001. These standards do not specify the ERANGE error.
```

(A) It looks like "Standards" are stating that it is undefined behavior , where glibc is making some tweaks to check the ranges.

(B) the scanf function requires a const format , everything else is not "checked" for sanity , eg to ensure that the Pointer has been allocated & has enough size to hold the input & matched the given conversion , Etc. In that Scenario , it is not much safer to check the range.

```
int scanf(const char *format, ...);
```

Comment: Re the final sentence: there is a big difference between writing correct code, and a user entering a value that will exceed the (programmer's) expected range, so it doesn't seem much of a justification.

Comment: For [language-lawyer] questions such as this one, we generally expect answers to rely for their authority on the language standard / specification.  Glibc manual pages may contain relevant information, but they are not a substitute for the language spec.  More specifically, this question is not about the behavior or documentation of Glibc; rather, it is explicitly about what the language specifications have to say.